# angular material mat-tab-nav-bar make logo on the left with tabs centered

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have a nav bar but I want the tabs in the centre with the logo on the left

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     [routerLink]="'/'">
    <img src="/assets/logo.jpg">
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link
     [routerLink]="'/find-property'"
     routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla1.isActive">
    Find Property
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link
     [routerLink]="'/manage-property'"
     routerLinkActive #rla2="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla2.isActive">
    List a Property
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add auto margins and make sure position is absolute if you want the tabs in the exact middle.

```
nav {
  .logo {
    img {
      height: 1.5em;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
      position: absolute;
    }
  }
  /deep/ .mat-tab-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```

and html with auto margins:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     class="logo"
     [routerLink]="'/'">
    <img src="/assets/logo.jpg">
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link
     style="margin-left: auto"
     [routerLink]="'/find-property'"
     routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla1.isActive">
    Find Property
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link
     style="margin-right: auto"
     [routerLink]="'/manage-property'"
     routerLinkActive #rla2="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla2.isActive">
    List a Property
  </a>
</nav>
```